# Array formula issue with MAX IF AND functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got an array formula which working well:

```
=MAX(IF( J3:K11<>"",VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(J3:K11,"wks",""))))
```

What if I want to add another condition which J3:K11<>"ABC" ?

I tried this but it's not working:

```
=MAX(IF( AND(J3:K11<>"", J3:K11<>"ABC"),VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(J3:K11,"wks",""))))
```

The array formula now returned with **0**.

Any reason why this happened and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

```
=MAX(IF((J3:K11<>"")*(J3:K11<>"ABC"),VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(J3:K11,"wks",""))))
```

Answer (score 1):

solved it with:

```
=MAX(IF(J4:K12<>"", IF(J4:K12<>"ABC", VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(J4:K12,"wks","")))))
```